# Can a Jewish, non-observant parent cook for his Orthodox child?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

Can a Jew who understands the laws of Kashrut but is not personally observant cook for a Kosher-observant Jew? 
For example, can a Jewish but non-observant parent cook for his Orthodox child?

Comment: related (although that question doesn't have a good answer yet): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35299/is-kosher-food-cooked-by-an-irreligious-jew-bishul-akum

Comment: @Hartzl Is that a dupe?

Comment: I believe so - I don't think the non-observant person being a parent makes a difference.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40778/how-to-keep-kosher-in-a-non-observant-household

Comment: See newly asked question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55932/can-a-non-kashrus-observant-jew-cook-for-a-kashrus-observant-jew I believe this question will get more useful answers.

Comment: @msh210 Can you change the duplicate from "Is kosher food cooked by an irreligious Jew Bishul Akum?"  to : judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55932/ ? If you check this question's history, you will see that the latter question is a better match for duplicate than the former.

Comment: @Bruce , I think we may have an answer for your question - please see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55932

Answer (score -3):

Both of you are Jewish. If you are concerned about the concept of 'Bishul Akum' - a Gentile turning on the stove, it obviously doesn't apply, here.

I understand that perhaps, you have a separate concern that your mom may bring in non-kosher food, may mix meat with dairy pots or cook food that is kosher but not to your kashrut standards. If these are concerns, you can explain your rules and needs to her, and hopefully, she will cooperate. In short, if she is using your own food and cookware and utensils, her level of observance is irrelevant.

Comment: Somebody who doesn't keep shabbes for example is considered non-jewish meaning gentile and his 'cooking' is bishul akum.

Comment: @havarka +1, you are on the right track. However, I don't believe that a non-observant Jew is considered gentile for all areas of Kashrus. (He definitely is considered fully Jewish in most other areas.) Can you give a proof for your assertion? I believe that is the halacha for Yayin Nesech. Do you know where that applies to bishul alum?

Comment: @havarka - I would really like to see a source for your claim, as this is new to me. I know that non-Shomer Shabbat store owners rarely get supervision from a Va'ad, but, AFAIK, no Va'ad has declared the place non-kosher, per se. They just don't recommend buying from there.

Comment: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 72:2
וכל המחלל את השבת בפרהסיא, הרי הוא כעובד כוכבים לכל דבריו: אם נוגע ביין – אוסרו, והפת שהוא אופה – הוי כמו פת של עובד כוכבים, וכן התבשיל שהוא מבשל – הוי כמו בישולי עובד כוכבים. ופרהסיא הוי בפני עשרה מישראל. ולאו דוקא שעושה בפניהם ממש, אלא שיודעין בהעבירה, דהכי מוכח בגמרא (בסנהדרין עד ב) ופוסקים, גבי "והא אסתר פרהסיא הוה", וכן כתב הפרי מגדים.
פירסום הוי עשרה מישראל, או שידע שיתפרסם.

Comment: cause they buy kosher but don't keep shabbes?
look http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4358
Pischei teshuva.. if kitzur is not good enough for you :), but if the real reason is chatnus, like maharit writes, and we are afraid that mumar lekolhatora kula is not allowed there is tshuva of rav moshe, that if you know that for example your mom wouldn't put something non-kosher in the pot cause she knows it's important for you and you can rely on her despite the fact she is non-religious than it would be ok.