Practical consequences of a Jew who worships Avodah Zara
Besides for the fact that avodah zara is an aveira, are there any restrictions that come about from a Jew who has this status? To narrow it down, let's say he keeps everything else in the Torah except for this one sin (and any other aveiras that are violated as a result of it). For example, can you eat food made by him?

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35299/is-kosher-food-cooked-by-an-irreligious-jew-bishul-akum

@Deuteronomy it kind of begs the question, would this case be of one that is an irreligious Jew? He keeps all of the other mitzvos including Shabbos.

What do you mean by "worship"? And what's "everything else" that he keeps"?

It is forbidden to give him to eat from the Korean Pesach (Rambam H. Korban Pesach 9:7); it is forbidden to eat from his Shecitah (H. Shechitah 4:14); it is forbidden to accept a sacrifice from him (H. Ma'asei Hakorbanot 3:4)

@AlBerko My understanding of avoda zara is serving false gods or idols. Obviously it is highly unlikely that someone who does so would keep all of the other mitzvos in the Torah, but when the yezter hara for it still existed, perhaps it wasn't so unlikely.  When i say "everything else" I mean that he keeps all of the other mitzvos of the Torah (Shabbos, tzitzis, bris milah, kosher, etc...)

Let's imagine meeting Jesus' brother Jacob who was a pious and observant Jew and let's presume that he held his brother to be God. Is this a good example? Because the observance of Jewish law with a completely different deity necessitates a different Torah or other narrative of divine revelation.

So according to Rabbinic tradition, he would be deemed an idolator, and now the question is whether he's be Mumar to a single Mitzva or Mumar to All of Torah. Rambam sees it as the former: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.13.17?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi
